# Selenium driver findElement by.xpath unable to access the last column in the table. Selenium RC code worked well

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-rc

Selenium driver: The last column in the table  (th[10]) is not  accessed by driver.findElement By.xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='collapseOne_DMTS']/div/table/thead/tr[1]/th[10]"));
```

I used the code to get the last (10th) element in the table (0-10). 
All other elements including element 9 are successfully retrieved by the code.
The code worked fine with Selenium RC:

```
selenium.getText("xpath=//*[@id='collapseOne_DMTS']/div/table/tbody/tr["+(i+1)+"]/td[10]");
```

- all elements of the table  were  accessed successfully.

Comment: We will need to see a sample of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Do not concatenate selectors. Use collections.

```
List<WebElement> columns = webDriver.FindElements(By.xpath("//*@id='collapseOne_DMTS']/div/table/thead/tr[1]/th"))
```